# Loop for copy and paste

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, copy-paste

I have data for the years beginning from 1921 to 2014 in Excel. Years are sorted by one under the other. I want to conduct time series analysis, but first I need to manage the data set that years are sorted side by side. The data is (years are in A column and values are in B column):

```
*1922 -> first 110 value
*1923 -> second 110 value
…
*2014 -> last 110 value
```

I want to organize data as:

```
*For 1922, moving data from B113:B223 to C2:D112
*For 1923, moving data from B224:B334 to D113:D223
*For 1924, moving data from B335:B445 to E224:E334
```

I wrote macro, it is very simple and not enough. There should be loop, but I could not figure it out:

```
Sub RangeTest()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim xRg As Range
    Set xRg = Application.Selection
    Range("B113:B223").Copy Range("C2:C112")
    xRg.Select
End Sub
```

I would be very grateful for your any help

Comment: Yes. I have 93 different years ending at 2014. The group of last year which is 2014 beginning from cell B10325 to B10435. Every year has the range of 110 cells by one under the other.

Comment: I did the above code but it composed every year into the cell C. The years should be: 1922 in column C, 1923 in column D, 1924 in column E,..., 2014 in column CQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C2=INDIRECT("R"&(COLUMN()*111+ROW()-222)&"C2", FALSE)
```

Drag down till C112.

Drag right till CQ2:CQ112.

Then select C2:CQ112, copy, paste special - values. if needed, of course.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much Akina! I've been struggling for weeks (actually I considered copy and paste manually by my hand finally). I'm very very grateful to you… Best regards